# How to test if occurrence distributions are equal with dependent variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

#### Description of the experiment

Each experiment is a performance done by an artist/athlete, and these are independent.

I have $k=4$ judges labelled $J\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ that can classify a performance into one of $m=5$ categories labelled $C=\{Elegant, Powerful, Graceful, Technical, Instinctive\}$.

Observing $N=200$ experiments we get the following table

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Elegant | 12 | 10 | 8 | 7 |
| Powerful | 27 | 28 | 27 | 28 |
| Graceful | 46 | 39 | 37 | 43 |
| Technical | 23 | 44 | 31 | 38 |
| Instinctive | 92 | 79 | 97 | 84 |

I want to test if the distribution that each judge assignes to a performance is the same.

Although the performances are independent, the evaluations of the judges are not, judge $1$ might find $Powerful$ the same features of the performance that judge $2$ might find $Technical$, so performances that the first one classifies as $Powerful$ the second one will classify them as $Technical$.

I think my hypothesis would be:

- $H_0$: The judges do not follow a distribution to classify the performances.
- $H_a$: All the judges (or pairwise) follow the same distribution.

#### Question: What test should I use?

I'm completely lost in what kind of test should I use as observations are correlated. If it is a Chi Square test, do I have my hypothesis inverted? What would the degrees of freedom be?.

Comment: *Although the performances are independent, the evaluations of the judges are not, judge 1 might find Powerful the same features of the performance that judge 2
 might find Technical, so performances that the first one classifies as Powerful
 the second one will classify them as Technical*---What do you mean here? Are you saying that if Judge 1 is rated powerful that Judge 2 is more likely to be rated technical?

Comment: I mean that judges might be dependent on one another, but not in a straight forward way.